# ¿Como escribo en un fichero de texto?

Tags: c#

soy más o menos nuevo en c#, en acceso a datos y demás, y necesito ir haciendo un log de por donde va mi programa hasta el final, para saber mediante `try catch` y demás como funciona.

Mi duda era, como puedo hacer que vaya escribiendo mensajes en líneas de texto he probado esto, y no escribe.

```
public static void Escribir(){

  file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:/ruta/log.txt");
  //Do stuff
  try{
    file.write("Ha llegado hasta linea X");
    file.close();
  }catch(Exception e){
    file.WriteLine(e.Message);
    file.close();
  }
```

Comment: El método a usar es **File.WriteAllLines()** NO File.WriteAllLine().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para escribir en un archivo puedes usar [File.WriteAllLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
        string path = ""C:/ruta/log.txt"";
        string texto = "Ha llegado hasta linea X";
        File.WriteAllLines(path, createText);
```

Incluso para no sobreescribir el contenido, si deseas agregar otro texto al contenido del archivo, puedes usar [File.AppendAllLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
        string path = ""C:/ruta/log.txt"";
        string texto = "Ha llegado hasta linea X";
        File.AppendAllLines(path, new String[] { texto });
```

---

Otro método para agregar texto a un archivo es mediante el uso de la clase [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
        string path = ""C:/ruta/log.txt"";
        string texto = "Ha llegado hasta linea X";

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(texto);
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por estos metodos, me los voy a tatuar para no olvidarlos!

Comment: Hehe, Excelente!!!, un saludo!

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza el metodo `File.WriteAllLines()` que es mucho mas facil de utilizar y te escribira cada elemento del array en una nueva linea:

```
File.WriteAllLine("C:/ruta/log.txt", new String[]{ "Ha llegado hasta linea X" });
File.WriteAllLine("C:/ruta/log.txt", new String[]{ "Esto se escribira en otra linea" });
```

Comment: Así tal cual, ¿No tengo que cerrar el file.close ni especificar la posición en el String[x]?

Comment: No tienes que cerrarlo, el metodo lo hace por ti. Y no hay que especificarle el indice. Que simple, verdad?

Comment: Joer, me solucionas la vida, muchísimas gracias :)

Comment: ¿Lo único, como creo el objeto, de la misma manera?

Comment: Puedes explicarte un poco mejor? No entendi.

Comment: Nada nada, ya está todo perfecto, muchísimas gracias :)